# systemd aborts in clock_gettime

Tags: linux, systemd, year2038

When booting systemd on a 5.4 kernel or later on a 32bit CPU, systemd aborts:

```
Assertion 'clock_gettime(map_clock_id(clock_id), &ts) == 0' failed at ../src/basic/time-util.c:55, function now(). Aborting.
```

Why?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Enable `CONFIG_COMPAT_32BIT_TIME` when building the Linux kernel. Doing so will enable the relevant syscall. When the syscall is unavailable, it will return `-ENOSYS` triggering the assertion.

It became easier to disable around 5.4 and can now be disabled by `allnoconfig`.

Comment: Where should someone enable that flag? Is there a resource somewhere explaining how/why?

Comment: That is a Linux kernel configuration flag. I've updated the answer to make it more clear.

Comment: So is it a flag available only when *building* a kernel? - it isn't obvious; I had that `clock_gettime...` error after a package upgrade, so no explicit building involved.

Comment: Yes, this is fully dependent on the configuration of the Linux kernel. Without the mentioned item, the relevant syscall is unavailable and systemd fails.